# Metro View in SharePoint using jquery

Tags: 2013, view

I am trying to create a metro view in one of my SharePoint sites based on the data that is retrieved from a list. Am a beginner on this. Can anyone help on how to start with a basic Metro view?

Please look at the attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: How will you get the list data? What methods are you planning to use? There is plenty Metro Tiles plugins for jQuery on the web. On the other hand, the promoted links list exists in SharePoint that could be styled with some CSS to get multiple lines of tiles and different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use Sharepoint native Promoted links. If you do not want to code javascript for it just go with Promoted Links and put some css.

Javascript code would be something like this:

1. prepare own site (it should have some div tag where javascript would put generated code)
2. Load list data
3. render list data in HTML and put it to DOM
4. style that HTML with css